# Access variables and lists from function

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I am new to unit testing with Python. I would like to test some functions in my code. In particular I need to test if the outputs have specific dimensions or the same dimensions.

My Python script for unit testing looks like this:

```
import unittest
from func import *

class myTests(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    # I am not really sure whats the purpose of this function

def test_main(self):
    # check if outputs of the function "main" are not empty:
    self.assertTrue(main, msg = 'The main() function provides no return values!')

    # check if "run['l_modeloutputs']" and "run['l_modeloutputs']", within the main() function have the same size:
    self.assertCountEqual(self, run['l_modeloutputs'], run['l_dataoutputs'], msg=None)  
    # --> Doesn't work so far!

    # check if the dimensions of "props['k_iso']", within the main() function are (80,40,100):

def tearDown(self):
    # I am also not sure of the purpose of this function

if _name__ == "__main__": 
    unittest.main()
```

Here is the code under test:

```
def main(param_file):
    # Load parameter file
    run, model, sequences, hydraulics, flowtrans, elements, mg = hu.model_setup(param_file)

    # some other code   
    ...   

    if 'l_modeloutputs' in run:
        if hydraulics['flag_gen'] is False:
            print('No hydraulic parameters generated. No model outputs saved')
        else:
            save_models(realdir, realname, mg, run['l_modeloutputs'], flowtrans, props['k_iso'], props['ktensors'])
```

I need to access the parameters `run['l_modeloutputs']` and `run['l_dataoutputs']` of the `main` function from `func.py`. How can I pass the dimensions of these parameters to the unit testing script?

Comment: What's the contents of `main` and `func.py`, roughly? Where are the values that you are looking to test generated? You say parameters, so you can just pass them, or do you mean variables local to `main`?

Comment: The func.py contains several functions like main(). Within the main function I load a parameter file (.ini) which contains initial parameters for a 3D model. The parameters are then processed and returned.
So with unitTesting I need to make sure that the processed and returned parameters contain again the same dimensions (the values of the parameters are of course different).

Comment: I'd say the problem here is the structure of your code. If you separated the parsing of the `param_file` out, and wrote a function that takes `run`, etc., as parameters, then it would be much easier to test that function. Similarly if the function returned the parameters (or returns `None` or throws an error if it can't) you could test the result independent of the saved file.

Comment: On editing, your test code appears to be broken; the indentation is off and I'd expect a `NameError` on `_name__`. Also note that rather than including nonsense comments like `I am not really sure whats the purpose of this function`, you could just delete those methods entirely until you *do* find a need for actions before or after each test.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit like one of two things at the moment. Either your code isn't laid out at the moment in a way that is easy to test, or maybe you are trying to test or call too much code in one go.

If your code is laid out like the following:

```
main(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as file:
        ... do work ...
        results = outcome_of_work
```

and you are trying to test what you have got from the `file_name` as well as the size of `results`, then you may want to think of refactoring this so that you can test a smaller action.  Maybe:

```
main(file_name):
    # `get_file_contents` appears to be `hu.model_setup`
    # `file_contents` would be `run`
    file_contents = get_file_contents(file_name)
    results = do_work_on_file_contents(file_contents)
```

Of course, if you already have a similar setup then the following is also applicable. This you can do easier tests, as you have easy control to both what's going into test (`file_name` or `file_contents`) and can then test the outcome (`file_contents` or `results`) for expected results.

With the `unittest` module you would basically be creating a small function for each test:

```
class Test(TestCase):

    def test_get_file_contents(self):
        # ... set up example `file-like object` ...
        run = hu.model_setup(file_name)
        self.assertCountEqual(
                run['l_modeloutputs'], run['l_dataoutputs'])

    ... repeat for other possible files ...

    def test_do_work_on_file_contents(self):
        example_input = ... setup input ...
        example_output = do_work_on_file_contents(example_input)
        assert example_output == as_expected
```

This can then be repeated for different sets of potential inputs, both good and edge cases.

Its probably worth looking about for a more in-depth tutorial as this is obviously only a very quick look over.

And `setUp` and `tearDown` are only needed if there is something to be done for each test you have written (i.e. you have set up an object in a particular way, for several tests, this can be done in `setUp` and its run before each test function.

Comment: To be honest, I am not 100% sure, if I get you right. Within my unitTesting-script you want me to load the parameter file and then test the initial parameters? To me that makes no sense, since the initial parameters are processed in the main-function.

Comment: So basically I need something like this:
The main-function returns the variables X,Y and Z. The variable X needs to have the dimensions 80*40*110. How can I test variable X in the external unitTesting script?

Comment: I've only noticed the information from `main` since I posted this. I'll edit the post to show `hu.model_setup(param_file)` as this seems to be what generates `run`

Comment: @EnzoBruckmamaan - Do you get notified of updates to answers? I just realized you may not. I have updated and hopefully its a bit clearer.

Comment: Yes I got them, thank you! I tried to use your example. However, I get the type error: "tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str" which refers to the values within self.assertCountEqual(). I changed it to the following:  

self.assertCountEqual(np.size(run['l_modeloutputs'],0), np.size(run['l_dataoutputs'],0)). But still, I get the same error. Any idea?

Comment: my example didn't unpack them. try either `run, model, sequences, hydraulics, flowtrans, elements, mg = hu.model_setup(file_name)` or refer to the first element for the assert - `self.assertCountEqual( run[0]['l_modeloutputs'], run[0]['l_dataoutputs'])`. If one of those works, I'll update.